# Do not show drill down results for faceted search

Tags: solr, django-haystack, solr4

I am using Haystack 2.4 and SOLR 4.* and trying to do the faceted search. This is my template:

```
<h4>By Author</h4>
<div>
    <dl>
        {% if facets.fields.author %}
            <dt>Author</dt>
            {# Provide only the top 5 authors #}
            {% for author in facets.fields.author|slice:":5" %}
                <dd><a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&amp;selected_facets=author_exact:{{ author.0|urlencode }}">{{ author.0 }}</a> ({{ author.1 }})</dd>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No author facets.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </dl>
```

But it just shows the top level results like:

```
author1 (20)
```

When I just to click author1 for the drill down results, nothing shows up. It just added up the url as 
http://localhost:8000/search/?q=test1&selected_facets=author_exact:author1&selected_facets=author_exact:author1&selected_facets=author_exact:author1

Anyone has any idea on it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is something related to my url.py configuration. I tried to use

```
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, facet_fields=['author']), name='haystack_search'), )
```

as mentioned in haystack faceted search documentation http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html

But I got error on unexpected keyword `facet_fileds`. I double checked haystack `FacetedSearchView` and `SearchView`'s init. It seems it does not have the init parameter for `facet_fields`. Then I switched to the following way which works fine for me.
`faceted_sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')
urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',url(r'^$',FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=faceted_sqs), name='haystack_search'), )`

If I got anything wrong, please point out. Thanks!